# reset counter in xslt v2.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Consider my XML File:

```
<Data>
  <VetaP dfg="2" ppp="oe"/>
  <VetaD ods="3" ds="oda"/>
  <VetaR date="080817"/>
  <VetaR date=""/>
  <VetaR date=""/>
  <VetaR date=""/>
  <VetaR date="080817"/>
  <VetaR date=""/>
  <VetaR date=""/>
  <VetaR date="080817"/>
</Data>
```

I need to add an attribute seq in `<VetaR>`, this attribute is a counter for every VetaR created. But, I need to reset the counter for every 5 occurrences of `<VetaR>`. I need to add also an attribute cnt, in which, it is also a counter, but this time it will only increment for every 5 occurrences of `<VetaR>`. I need to remove also the empty attributes.

Here is my XSLT code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Data">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv 5">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                <xsl:with-param name="group-pos" select="position()"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="VetaR">
    <xsl:param name="group-pos"/>
    <VetaR seq="{position()}" cnt="{$group-pos}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    </VetaR>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="VetaR/@*[not(normalize-space())]"/>
```

Current Output:

```
<Data>
  <VetaP dfg="2" ppp="oe"/>
  <VetaD ods="3" ds="oda"/>
  <VetaR seq="3" cnt="1" date="080817"/>
  <VetaR seq="4" cnt="1"/>
  <VetaR seq="5" cnt="1"/>
  <VetaR seq="1" cnt="2"/>
  <VetaR seq="2" cnt="2" date="080817"/>
  <VetaR seq="3" cnt="2"/>
  <VetaR seq="4" cnt="2"/>
  <VetaR seq="5" cnt="2" date="080817"/></Data>
```

Desired Output:

```
  <Data>
  <VetaP dfg="2" ppp="oe"/>
  <VetaD ods="3" ds="oda"/>
  <VetaR seq="1" cnt="1" date="080817"/>
  <VetaR seq="2" cnt="1"/>
  <VetaR seq="3" cnt="1"/>
  <VetaR seq="4" cnt="1"/>
  <VetaR seq="5" cnt="1" date="080817"/>
  <VetaR seq="1" cnt="2"/>
  <VetaR seq="2" cnt="2"/>
  <VetaR seq="3" cnt="2" date="080817"/></Data>
```

Comment: By thinking of this in terms of resetting counters, you are thinking about how you would solve the problem if you were using a procedural programming language rather than a functional one. Try to get away from "telling the computer what to do", instead you should be thinking in terms of describing how the output relates to the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would tackle it as positional grouping:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Data">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv 5">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                    <xsl:with-param name="group-pos" select="position()"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="VetaR">
        <xsl:param name="group-pos"/>
        <VetaR seq="{position()}" cnt="{$group-pos}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        </VetaR>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="VetaR/@*[not(normalize-space())]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks!what if, I have other element before the VetaR? I can't get the correct output, the position started at 2. Updated input file.

Comment: Well, if the other elements are known to be before all the `VetaR` elements then you can easily fix the code by processing them first and separately with e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="* except VetaR"/><xsl:for-each-group select="VetaR" group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv 5">...</xsl:for-each-group>`. If the input is more variable then I guess you will need to show us more details of the input and the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply:

```
<xsl:template match="VetaR">
    <VetaR seq="{(position() - 1)  mod 5 + 1}" cnt="{(position() - 1) idiv 5 + 1}">
        <xsl:if test="string(@date)">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@date"/>
        </xsl:if>
     </VetaR>
</xsl:template>
```